# Why am I getting signal SIGABRT?

Tags: swift, uitableview, sigabrt

I'm trying to access a UIViewController from a UITableViewController , so far I've written this in the TableViewController class

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      let postVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SeePost")
              self.navigationController?.pushViewController(postVC, animated: true)

  }
```

but when I run the app and click a cell the app crashes giving me signal SIGABRT. How should I solve this ?

Comment: Check Identifier of UIViewController is correct or not.

Comment: and also check storyboard object "storyboard!"

Comment: Which line exactly? `storyboard!` is nil? How did you init your ViewController?

Comment: I already did these

Comment: Signal SIGABRT appears in the App Delegate

Comment: change your `didDeselectRowAt` to `didSelect`

Comment: What do you have in `postVC` life cycle methods. View did load, view will appear etc.

Comment: I only have viewDidLoad ,where I change the corner radius of a view

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using didDeselectRowAt? Why not didSelectRowAt?

Make sure your storyboard ID for the destination view controller is set to "SeePost" in storyboard (according to your case).
Also type case it as following:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let postVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SeePost") as! PostViewController
```

Change "PostViewController" to whatever name you have for your destination view controller.

Comment: did you change didDeselectRowAt  to didSelectRowAt?